# NSFetchedResultsController group into sections for every 4 hours

Tags: core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I'm attempting to group a series of NSManagedObjects into sections. Every section would represent a period of 4 hours within a day.

```m
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
{
    // Create and cache the section identifier on demand.

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    if (!tmp)
    {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit) fromDate:[self created]];
        tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f %d %d %d", round(components.hour % 4), components.day, components.month, components.year];
        [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

In the above code, found in the NSManagedObject, the transient property `sectionIdentifier` returns a string consisting of the period (of 4 hours) it is in, the day, month, and year of it's creation.

However, although the sort descriptor for the NSFetchedResultController's fetchRequest is set to sort the results in order of their creation date (newest objects at the bottom, oldest at the top), the fetch request is failing due to the section identifier not being ordered properly.

```m
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PSSpace" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES]]];
        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:nil];
        [_fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

> CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) The fetched object at index 10 has an out of order section name '1 14 12 2013. Objects must be sorted by section name'

Please can you tell me how I can fix this issue with the ordering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```m
if (!tmp) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit) fromDate:[self created]];

    NSUInteger _y = (components.year * 1000000);
    NSUInteger _m = (components.month * 10000);
    NSUInteger _d = (components.day * 100);
    NSUInteger _h = round(components.hour / 4);

    NSUInteger token = (_y + _m + _d + _h);

    tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", token];

    [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
}
```

Comment: That's effectively doing the same as what I'm doing at the moment. The issue lies where I'm working out what period of 4 the date is in. I need to be replacing components.hour % 4 with something else to work out the period.

Comment: @max_: It's not the same. This code (almost) produces a sectionIdentifier of the form "YYYYMMDDHH", which generates a relative ordering that is *compatible* with the first sort descriptor "created". Things that are still to fix (as it seems to me): Use a fixed with format, and `hour/4` instead of `hour % 4`.

Comment: @MartinR that fixed it, realised a bit earlier that I was using the wrong operator. Thanks for taking the time to look at the q! If you want, add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @max_: farski had it almost correct. I would suggest that he fixes the last bits, then you can accept it.

Comment: I fixed the operator. There may be other corrections, and it may be more efficient to just ensure month, day, and hour get 0-padded so you can just format the string rather than having do to the multiplication.

Comment: @farski It's easier just to do this, and then run `-componentsSeparatedByString:`. `tmp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f %d %d %d", ceil(components.hour / 4), components.day, components.month, components.year];`